# SCCM OSD TS End User Summary Screen

Tags: sccm

I am looking for a good way to make a summary to existing large build TS.

What I am working with is SCCM 2012r2 and what I need is a hint, how to capture all steps I want(some of them are in various groups) and put result of them in some sort of variable so at the end, someone who is building that PC will have a table showing lets say 30 of applications green and 4 of them red as a failure.

Can it be done in some easy way? I just need someone building the PC to see what app didn't install so he can install it manually or at least provide me more information before I'll dive into logs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say easy because it requires lots of steps and you have to do it per application manually basically but there is a TS Variable _SMSTSLastActionSucceeded which you could check after each installation step (you have to set the step to continue on error to make this work). So basically after you tried to install you check whether it worked and then set a TS variable of your choice to reflect the failure.
As a final step you implement a script that checks all your TS variables and outputs the result.

You could even use the addon [OSDBackground](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Replacement-for-BGInfo-0095cff3) to display your errors as the background image.

Some lengthy article how to implement a form of error handling can be found [here](https://ccmexec.com/2016/12/error-handling-in-ts-without-mdt-using-osdbackground/) however you would have to do this quite a bit different because in this example the ts fails at the first error and you want to continue and log but you should get the basic principles.